# Append select option with space

Tags: jquery

I am having an issue populating a select with options from an array of objects. Here is the array that gets passed:

```
data: [ { name: 'James'   },
        { name: 'James 2' },
        { name: 'Peter'   },
        { name: 'Paul'    } ]
```

My goal is then to populate a select called "scheduleSelect" with the options inside "data". The code below works for all the values except for James 2, where the option value gets set to 'James' and then the number 2 appears outside of the quotation marks. Here's my code:

```
var arrayLength = data.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    $('#scheduleSelect').append('<option value='+data[i]["name"]+'>'+data[i]["name"]+'</option>')
};
```

Here's the wonky output:

```
<option value="James">James</option>
<option value="James" 2>James 2</option>
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/):

```
data.forEach(function(v) {
    var $opt = $('<option>');
    $opt.val(v.name).text(v.name);
    $opt.appendTo('#scheduleSelect');
};
```

Here I am creating a new `option` and appending it to your existing select. I've also changed to using `forEach` for easier looping.

However, for performance reasons (if you're looping through a lot more than 4), I would recommend creating plain old DOM objects:

```
data.forEach(function(v) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.textContent = v.name;
    opt.value = v.name;
    $('#scheduleSelect').append(opt);
};
```

Comment: Remember that `forEach` isn't available in older browsers (IE 8, etc.)

Comment: There is no reason to create a new jQuery object for each data entry. It will only slow things down.

Comment: Thank you - this elegant solution worked, as did Thomas' fix below. I am interested about the question of creating a new jQuery object for each data entry. For something this small, it probably doesn't matter, but what about for larger arrays? How much more expensive is it to create a new <option> object every time rather than just generate the html code recursively as I was doing?

Comment: You'll have to run jsPerf tests to determine the performance increase, however I've edited my answer to include the creation of native DOM objects.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you don't have quotation marks around the `value` attribute, so the browser takes everything until the next space as the value.

This will work:

```
append('<option value="'+data[i]["name"]+'">'+data[i]["name"]+'</option>')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var data = [ { name: 'James'   },
          { name: 'James 2' },
          { name: 'Peter'   },
          { name: 'Paul'    } ];

var arrayLength = data.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
      $('#scheduleSelect').append('<option value='+data[i]["name"]+'>'+data[i]["name"]+'</option>')
    }
```

This is the fiddle working: http://jsfiddle.net/y588cfo5/